# Why isn't the *textToShare appearing after clicking my @"Share" button?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, share, ibaction

I want to it so when a player presses the @"share" button they can text and email a message and url to a friend. The code I wrote says a message and url but when I press Share and then either messages or email it's just an empty text box.

Also the last line seems to have problems.

It tells me there's NO visible @interface for 'MyScene' declares the selector 'presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion'

This is my IBAction

```
- (IBAction)shareAction:(id)sender {
//  
  NSLog(@"share");
 NSString *textToShare = @"YOOO CHECK IT OUT";
  UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beck.png"];

  NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

 NSArray *activityItems = @[textToShare, imageToShare, urlToShare];
 UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
 activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage,                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];

 UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(NSString *activityType,BOOL completed) {
NSLog(@"%@", activityType);
if(completed) {
  NSLog(@"completed");
} else
{
  NSLog(@"cancled");
}
[activityVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
 };
 activityVC.completionHandler = myBlock;
 [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Did you type this code in a subclass of `UIView`? nor a `ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

You have mention **mail and message** in **excludedActivityType** then how come it will in uiActivityViewController

remove Both from exclude and try to run.

Comment: Yeah thanks, not sure why I didn't notice that. After removing that the message still doesn't appear but i'm a step closer so thank you.

Comment: Another thing is that you are passing image for sharing but by reading [this](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/) reference image is not supporting to share in mail or message